# Efficient Triangular Backsubstitution in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-algebra

I am interested in solving the linear system of equations Ax=b where A is a lower-triangular matrix (n × n) and b is a (n × 1) vector where n ≈ 600k.

I coded up backsubstitution in R and it works fast for matrices of size upto 1000, but is really slow for larger n (≈ 600k). I know that the naive backsubstitution is O(n^2).

My R function is below; does anyone know of a more efficient (vectorized, parallelized etc.) way of doing it, which scales to large n?

## Backsubstitution

```
backsub=function(X,y)
{ 
 l=dim(X)
 n=l[1]  
 p=l[2]
 y=as.matrix(y)
    
   for (j in seq(p,1,-1))
    {  
      y[j,1]=y[j,1]/X[j,j]
      if((j-1)>0)
         y[1:(j-1),1]=y[1:(j-1),1]-(y[j,1]*X[1:(j-1),j])
    }  
    return(y)
}
```

Comment: Interesting question.  Have you benchmarked it against `solve()`?  I would imagine that the native solve function would be fairly efficient.

Comment: solve() won't exploit the triangular structure of the matrix and would just give the naive O(n^3).

Comment: Interesting.  So basically the matrix is already in reduced form, and you're trying to exploit that.  I have no idea but +1 interesting question.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, its a lower triangular matrix and thats the reason why backsubstitution can work.

Comment: @BladeRunner Back substitution is by definition a sequential operation; I'm not sure it can be improved by parallelization (unless there is some matrix magic I am unaware of). If you are familiar with matlab, the second example here: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece204/howtos/backward/ may be more efficient (I can't confirm), as your implementation looks like the first example

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I have. That's textbook "backsub". Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about the R function `backsolve`? It calls the [Level 3 BLAS routine dtrsm](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/da7/dtrsm_8f.html) which is probably what you want to be doing. In general, you won't beat BLAS/LAPACK linear algebra routines: they're insanely optimized.